# What are the major differences between SET and SSL?

Tags: tls

SET and SSL are usually used as secure payment protocols. What are the major differences between them? Which one is better?

Comment: Take a look at this . this might be helpful. https://www.slideshare.net/rameshogania/ssl-tsl-set

Answer (score 1):

#### TLS

TLS (SSL) is a general, not payment-specific protocol. Most important in the context of this question, it is current best practice.

#### SET

SET was introduced around 1996 and declared dead around 2003.